# jQuery calculate amount of days and hide checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a duration of for example 3 days, and 7 checkboxes that represent each day in a week.
I want to be able to check one day, and then hide the next 2 days (3 days total).

[image]

If we consider a duration of 3 days:
I check Monday, then tuesday & wednesday will be hidden. 
I can then check thursday, then friday & saturday will be hidden:

[image]

I wrote the following that partially works:

```
var toHide = new Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
$('.days').change(function() {
 var val = $(this).val();
 var duration = $('#duration').val();
 if($('#check'+val).prop('checked')) {
    scheduleSelection(val,duration,'on');
 }else{
    scheduleSelection(val,duration,'off');
 }
});

function scheduleSelection(id,duration,mode) {
 var totalDays = duration;
 if(totalDays>1) {
  totalDays--;
    var next = parseInt(id)+1;
    for(i=1;i<=totalDays;i++) {
        if(next>7) { next = 1; }
        if(mode=='on') {
            toHide[next] = 1;
            $('#check'+next).hide();
        }else{
            toHide[next] = 0;
            $('#check'+next).show();
        }
        next++;
    }
 }
}
```

The problem here is if you were to check Monday then tuesday & wednesday will be hidden, but if you then check saturday, there is a collision as sunday & monday will be hidden, yet tuesday & wednesday will remain hidden:

[image]

Please see **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ndaj4x3L/1/)**

Any pointers in the right direction is appreciated

Comment: what happens when checked on `Sun`?

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: When checking Sunday, there is an overlap of monday (which is already checked), so id like monday to uncheck, and keep only monday, tuesday hidden

Comment: @Sandersen in your text box, the value is three, but hiding checkboxes are two, is this the required functionality?

Comment: @ameenulla0007 The idea is that the checked day is included in the amount of days, which is why i remove 1 from totalDays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like Pablo's answer. I think you should use that instead. My solution works but is a little dirty. Here it is anyway: https://jsfiddle.net/ndaj4x3L/3/

```
if($('#check'+next).is(":checked")) {
    $('#check'+next).trigger('click');
    $('#check'+next).hide();
    $('#check'+id).trigger('change');
}
```

EDIT: The reason I trigger the change again after I triggered the click is because for some reason the loop stops after the function runs again. Could be something to do with variable names being the same or something, I am not really sure, but that should fix it anyway.

Comment: Amazing. Just what i was looking for. So simple ;) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you hide also the preview days  and uncheck the hidden elements could be a good solution.

```
function scheduleSelection(id,duration,mode) {
//var oneDay = 86400;
var totalDays = duration;

if(totalDays>1) {
    totalDays--;
    var next = parseInt(id)+1;
    var prev = parseInt(id)-1;
    for(i=1;i<=totalDays;i++) {
        if(next>7) { next = 1; }
        if(prev<1) { prev = 7; }
        if(mode=='on') {
            toHide[next] = 1;
            toHide[prev] = 1
            $('#check'+next).hide();
            $('#check'+next).attr("checked",false);
            $('#check'+prev).hide();
            $('#check'+prev).attr("checked",false);
        }else{
            toHide[next] = 0;
            toHide[prev] = 0;
            $('#check'+prev).show();
            $('#check'+next).show();
        }
        next++;
        prev--;
    }
  }
}
```

[example jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/678eupyd/2/)